# copy pairs of files with same filename and different file extension

Tags: copy

So I'm trying to copy files for statements so there is a pdf and an xml file with the same name and different file extensions. I need to copy lets say 1000 files at a time so that would be 500 pairs of pdf and xml files. I'm trying setup a batch file to do this, but I'm not sure how to get it to check the filenames to get the pair to copy at the same time. The reason I need the pair is because if just one or the other is there it will bomb out and not process. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Corey